# Etymology of "dog slow"

Tags: idioms, adjectives, etymology

When I think of dogs I have an image of them being fast animals, running and jumping, chasing a ball or another dog.

So, I am surprised that [dog slow](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dog_slow) means very slow.

What is the etymology of this expression?

Usage in the wild ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531695/how-to-print-the-current-stack-trace-in-net-without-any-exception) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311599/why-is-androids-string-format-dog-slow)):

> Keep in mind that StackTrace is dog slow - so use it sparingly.
>
> Why is android's String.format dog slow?

Comment: I just found this old forum thread with more speculation, someone claiming the expression was printed in PCWorld Magazine, and a person from Texas saying it "*is not unusual in American English*": https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/dog-slow.1922871/ Someone says "dog" might be short for "doggone".

Answer (score 5):

The [entry for "dog" in the Online Etymology Dictionary](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=dog) is interesting

> In ancient times, "the dog" was the worst throw in dice (attested in Greek, Latin, and Sanskrit, where the word for "the lucky player" was literally "the dog-killer"), which plausibly explains the Greek word for "danger," kindynas, which appears to be "play the dog."

[The Free Dictionary definition of dog](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dog) includes a more general slang usage of "dog" that I'm familiar with:

> Something of inferior or low quality: "The President had read the speech to some of his friends and they told him it was a dog" (John P. Roche).

Another example:

> I bought a laptop from Cheep Computerz, but it was a real dog. I wouldn't buy anything from them again.

I would suggest that "dog slow" comes from the same usage. It's as slow as a really inferior thing.

Answer (score -2):

In real life, dogs (especially wild mutts) are often scrappy and sickly. If you've ever noticed dogs in a third world country, you know exactly what I mean. In slang, a "dog" can be anything that is ugly or ragged or homely. For example, in the classic movie *Marty*, the lead character constantly refers to himself as a "dog," because he thinks of himself as unattractive. My guess would be that the origin comes from this meaning. A ragged, old dog of a car, for example, is not going to run well, and it's certainly not going to look or handle like a fancy sports car. You could refer to a car like this as "dog slow."

Comment: Yeah except answers here are not supposed to be guesses.

Comment: I tried to find the etymology but there doesn't appear to be any ideas offered.

Comment: I'm not sure you're right about guessing.

Comment: I could only find this meta question: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/how-useful-are-references-and-should-their-usage-be-more-encouraged-on-ell

Comment: Well, the way I see it, I can answer however I please, and people can downvote if they like. I feel like, even if I'm wrong, at least I'm offering a reasonable idea worth pondering. A "dog" is such a familiar, common thing in human life -- it seems like it would be difficult to be able to pinpoint the etymology beyond all doubt. In the absence of an agreed-upon word origin, I believe a reasonable, thoughtful guess is better than nothing.