# "Dog" can mean "something of an inferior quality". What animals do we use, if any, to describe the opposite?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

The noun, dog, can be used to indicate something of an unattractive/unworthy feature/quality.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dog) defines it as

> 8: one inferior of its kind
>
> **the movie was a dog** : such as a: an investment not worth its price
>
> b: an undesirable piece of merchandise

What animal(s), if any, do we use for the opposite, the adored/worthy objects?

Comment: There is no animal that has that meaning. You might say **masterpiece**.

Comment: We lionize people... https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lionize

Comment: For people, we have "king of the jungle" or "top dog" but I've not heard of one for objects / products. I'd also never heard of this kind of usage for "dog", so YMMV.

Comment: It's all about context, as in the non-PC joke, 'What's the difference between a dog and a fox?'

Comment: Maybe slang - but calling something 'a dog' is common enough in England.  Conversely the 'dogs danglies' or similar (more uncouth) phrases can and are used to mean the opposite.  I.e.  'That Ferrari is the dogs danglies' (the Ferrrari is superflous in it's greatness) compared with - 'That Lada is an absolute dog' (don't buy the Lada - it's rubbish).

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/140818/9161

Comment: @charmer Perhaps in **parts of** England. I'm English and I've never heard this usage (except specifically about unattractive women).

Comment: A bad movie is typically called a turkey, not a dog...

Comment: Not an animal, but something can be a peach.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist  That'll be the parts of England that are no higher class than lower middle then.  True that 'dog' is often (but not exclusively) reserved as a comment on 'unattractive women' (by men) or 'unattractive men' (by women).  I find it difficult to believe that you've never heard or read the phrase 'the dogs b****cks' to refer to something.  You've only got to watch one episode of the Clarkson era Top Gear to hear the phrase I'm sure.

Comment: You could say "god," which coincidentally is "dog" backwards ;)

Comment: You could say **goat**. It technically fits, although its usage is as an acronym for Greatest of All Time.

Comment: OP, not an animal, but you can use "Peach" to mean "excellent". The house for sale is a real peach, that used car is a peach, etc.  There is no animal for the usage.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that "dog" **can be used in a positive**, sort of macho way - "you dog!"

Comment: "Dog" is very flexible, actually. It is like this Monty Python famous F word. It can mean many different things and the meaning depends on how you say it =)

Comment: @user3445853 I'm an American, and have definitely heard of movies called "dogs" by other Americans.

Comment: Cat's meow: from Merriam Webster " a highly admired person or thing".  Although I don't think it is in common use.  Tried to check the frequency of usage but I think it is conflated with people looking for cat videos...  Can't post this as an anwer.

Comment: How about 'throroughbred'?

Comment: To follow up on the "Dogs b*****cks comment, it's actually worse than that because it can be shortened to "The Dogs".  So a Ferrari is "The Dogs", but a Lada is "A dog".

Comment: I am a native speaker and I have never heard this usage before. Except perhaps in the term, 'working like a dog'.

Answer (score 22):

It's not an exact opposite, but the mythical animal **"unicorn"** is sometimes used as a description for people and things that are so rare and special that they may seem nearly mythical. For instance, at my company, the most senior developers are jokingly referred to as "unicorns" because it's very rare for a developer to get promoted to that level --there are very few of them in the whole company.

Also --it's outdated slang at this point, but at one time "dog" and **"fox"** were paired opposites meaning "ugly" and "beautiful" in reference to people (most often used by boys when talking about girls). Thus "she's a dog" and "she's a fox" would be two sentences using this slang, but with opposite meanings. These usages would likely be received as offensive in modern conversation (or at least the first one would --you still occasionally do hear "she's a fox" or "he's a fox"). As noted in the comments below, **vixen** (literally "female fox") has a similar meaning and usage, but is more explicitly sexual, which makes it more likely to be received as offensive.

Comment: Unicorn and Fox are both good although I think fox is better. Tiger is another one. In fact most phrases of the form "<attribute> as a <animal>" could work. Strong as an ox etc

Comment: Great answer!@  Good one!

Comment: Completely random point, a lot of new English users don't realize that **"vixen"** is a "female fox".  (Come to think of it, I bet many native speakers don't know that, which is depressing.)

Comment: Great care and consideration regarding decorum should be taken when ascribing unicorn, fox, or vixen to humans. They are all primarily sexual in nature without a special context such as @Chris Sunami's usage.

Comment: @Yorik Fox and especially vixen are certainly sexually charged terms, but unicorn has no sexual connotations at all in my opinion.

Comment: I would consider "thoroughbred", as it brings to mind a pure version of something intended to perform at the highest level.

Comment: @AeonAkechi - You must not be familiar with the meaning given in [liljoshu's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/232201/272). It's the first thing I would assume is meant if someone is called a unicorn.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Liljoshu's definition is just a particular case of the usage of "unicorn" to mean someone or something exceedingly rare and possibly non-existent.  The sexual component in that case is incidental.

Answer (score 19):

The [slang word "beast"](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/beast) can be used to describe something that's awesome. [For example](http://thestrangeverse.blogspot.com/p/my-favorite-movies.html):

> This movie was a BEAST, cast wonderfully, directed excellently, acted superbly and just all around incredible, and the theme of the movie "Hero" by Chad Kroger is officially my theme song for whenever it's time for me to get down to business.

Comment: Be aware of potentially unsavoury meanings, though, especially for people: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beast

Comment: Also used as an adjective in the form "beasty," which is less common, but more unambigiously positive --"that movie was **beasty**".  Not to be confused with "beastly" which is neither slang nor positive.

Comment: Calling something “a beast” isn’t quite saying it’s *good*, so much as *powerful* or *impressive*.  It’s often positive, but not automatically.

Comment: @PLL - it's difficult for non-native speakers to really grasp the typical use of "beast", and also notably "beast mode" unless you are "in to" the US sports scene, particularly football.

Answer (score 13):

Not exactly an animal but more of a part of an animal, but both of the following expressions can be used to express a worthy/positive experience:

[bee's knees:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bee%27s%20knees)

> a highly admired person or thing

[dog's b*llocks:](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dog%27s%20Bollocks)

> the best.  It comes from the habit of male dog's licking their testicles and that they must taste good as they spend so much time in this activity.

In your example, you could say: *That movie yesterday was the bee's knees/dog's b*llocks*.

Comment: Of similar meaning (and similar vintage), there is also the expression "the cat's pajamas".

Comment: Warning for English learners: "dog's bollocks" may be considered as rude, offensive, even obscene in some parts of the Anglosphere. Even in England, there are social contexts where it would not be the right choice.

Comment: Obscene _maybe_. Rude or offensive? Nah mate.

Comment: As well, in Australia we use [duck's nuts](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/resources/aus/word/map/search/word/duck's%20nuts/North%20Coast%20Qld/)

Comment: @mcalex - somewhat a contradiction in terms? Or are Aussi ducks different..?

Comment: In US you might hear that something or someone is the "cat's ass"

Comment: It's important to note that the "etymology" given on the comic urban dictionary site, and repeated above in yellow, is utter nonsense.  (Intriguingly, there is a **history** of utterly ridiculous folk etymologies of the phrase "dog's bollocks"; anyone interested can google this.)

Comment: The **cat's *meow*** is the version I learnt ...

Comment: @Tim I assume you're referring to the fact that "duck" technically only refers to females while "drake" is used for males?  This is not really true, however, as the word "duck" is commonly used throughout the English-speaking world to refer to either sex.

Comment: @Tim if bees can have knees ...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - true enough - there are even breeds that have the name within - shelduck being one. Although *sheldrakes* exist too..Maybe that's how Donald got away with it?

Comment: @mcalex - I'm sure they can if they want to! Impossible to articulate legs without. There again, they spend more time using other appendages.

Comment: @Fattie is there a more definitive version regarding the origin of the phrase? I'll happily link to a more trustworthy resource than UD.

Answer (score 10):

Many animal words in English have both positive and negative connotations, simultaneously. 'Dog' isn't always negative, but also also not always positive. The use of animal terms in relation of people is *generally* (but not always) used to denote a type of personality, not necessarily "good" or "bad". There are some exclusively bad or good though, so I'll try to make note of how each is perceived.

**Swan**

Swans are often used to describe grace and beauty, and are considered a superior animal compared to the duck. More upper-crusted in use. You can say something like, "She's an ugly duckling now, but she'll be a swan later." You can also say things like "She's a swan on the ice."... Downside is a swan is considered fragile and not down-to-earth. May sometimes be considered self-centered.

**Ugly Duckling**

Calling something an "Ugly Duckling" saying they're ugly now, that they stand out or look worse than their peers now, but will be a swan later.

**Spring Chicken**

Which means young and vibrant. So you can say, "She's a real spring chicken" or "I'm not a spring chicken anymore." That said, this is kind of dated terminology, and will make you sound like you're not a spring chicken. Also rural in origin. Has the negative connotation of being unexperienced.

**Wolf**

This means you're strong and independent ... but has a connotation of being a predator. "And the wolf went out on the dance floor."

**Snake**

This means clever and often (but not always) good looking ... but also not to be trusted. "And John came in, he was a real snake."

**Dawg**

Inner city slang. Opposed to "Dog", "Dawg" means a friend who is loyal and sticks close to you, even if they're both referencing the same animal. For example, "How's it going, Dawg?" Note that you must emphasize the "a" or it could be offensive due to being misinterpreted as "Dog".

**Dog**

Someone who is uncouth, uncultured, and unwise, but also very obedient and loyal... if handled properly. E.g. "Fred's a real dog..."

**Prize Pig**

Country slang. Means someone who is seen as high value and quality... to the right person, can be simultaneously complimenting and insulting. (Not to be confused with just "Pig" which is someone who is a slob.) For example, "Well, look at the prize pig up 'thar."

**Pig**

Someone who is messy and dirty and/or rude. Really not a positive connotation in any way. "He's a real pig." The rude meaning is almost exclusively used with men. HOWEVER... can also be a *very rude* way to refer to police officers. "Tony has the pigs on his back"

**Showdog**

Someone who looks good and is a showman... but also not very complicated. "Wow, look at the showdog up there."

**Hoss**

Believed by many to be a derivative of "Horse" (although possibly deriving 
 from a celebrity named Hoss), inner city slang. "Hoss" means a very attractive male who is likely well-endowed in bed. Like "Dawg", the "a" sound is emphasized. Pronounced to it rhymes with "Sauce" e.g. "He's a real haws." Downside: There isn't much else to them.

**Goose**

Someone who's fun... but can also be a minor problem. For example, "She was just a silly goose." It's a pretty regional term though. Also, not be confused with the *act* of goosing, which is pinching someone's butt. (Not to be confused with "Golden Goose" which other answers here mention).

**Parasite**

This one is actually always bad. It means someone who takes from people constantly and never gives back.

**Batty**

People generally aren't called a bat, but they *are* called "Batty". It means kind of quirky, a little nuts, but generally harmless, and sometimes a source of amusement. "She's really batty." The one exception to not getting called a bat though is an older woman who can be called, specifically, "An old bat" which means about the same as batty or an older woman who is more emotionally cold.

Also, do not confuse with "Batman" which is a fictional character and being called "Batman" means you're being called rich, powerful, strong, larger than life, and there's a good chance it's not seriously meaning it. example: "I'm Batman"

**Whale**

Fat. Very fat. Also very insulting. Unless used in reference to online gaming, in which case it means someone rich who keeps free-to-play games free for everyone else by buying all the optional stuff. example for both: "She's a whale."

**Shark**

Someone clever, sneaky, predatory, and definitely out to get you, likely by scamming you in games of chance by having some unconventional skill like card counting. "Watch out for Lenny, he's a real card shark."

**Jellyfish**

Someone who can't stand up for themselves, synonym with "spineless". Example, "Don't be such a jellyfish."

**Chicken**

A Coward. Someone who runs at the first sign of trouble. Example, "What are you, Chicken?"

**Cow**

Fat. Not as bad as whale, however, unlike whale, doesn't mean they spend a lot at video games though. primarily used with women. Considered very rude, and would likely have nearby people get angry with you.

Alternatively, can mean an unpleasant woman.

**Sheep**

Mindless and obedient, cannot think for themselves... however, used in a positive context in religion to... mean pretty much the exact same thing. Example, "They are a bunch of sheep."

**Worm**

Someone who is always underfoot trying to appeal to superiors. Generally considered to have no redeeming qualities other than being an easy pawn to use who knows they're a pawn (and potentially dangerous if they see an opportunity to grab power for themselves.) "Lenny's a stooge and a real worm."

**Unicorn**

A unicorn can reference an ideal person for a certain situation that doesn't exist. For example, a business wanting to hire someone with 10 years of a experience with a program that's been out for 3 years, they're looking for a unicorn. (And if they *do* find such a person, such as the person who *wrote* the program and spent 10 years doing so before release, that person is a unicorn.) Example, "That last candidate was a unicorn. Don't lose them!" or "Who you're looking for a unicorn, you'll never find them."

Possibly starting as a derivative of the above, in the lgbtq subcultures, a unicorn means a sexually attractive and active woman who is bisexual and polyamorous. Or even simply someone single, gay, and available. Generally denotes someone desirable who is non-monogomous. Example, "He's a cute unicorn." or "We're having a get-together of local unicorns."

**Stallion**

Primarily means a sexually attractive and active man who enjoys many romantic entanglements. Can be either straight or gay. Generally denotes someone desirable who is non-monogomous.

**Cold Fish**

Someone is is not sexually active or romantically fulfilling. Generally used more insulting or referencing an unfulfilling marriage. "Poor Susan, she married a real cold fish."

**Catty**

People aren't generally called cats, but they are called Catty. This means someone who thinks they're better than other people, and is quick to point out the failings of others. Example, "Hey, don't be catty."

Not to be confused with "Catgirl" or "Catboy" which is used as Anime subculture slang to refer to someone who is playful, flirty, and cutely attractive.

Comment: I believe that "wolf" would additionally carry the connotation of being a predator.  To me that removes it from the list of "adored/worthy" creatures - unless you also intend the predator meaning.  In my experience "snake" doesn't imply good looking (I agree with a snake being both clever and not to be trusted).

Comment: @J.ChrisCompton I have heard wolf used that way too, as well as snake. I'll update just so there's different connotations used.

Comment: "If someone refers to an old person, especially an old woman, as an old bat, they think that person is silly, annoying, or unpleasant." [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/old-bat)

Comment: Unicorn - never heard of that meaning... more like https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/career/unicorn-employees

Comment: Ugly Duckling is a reference to the literary fairy tale by Danish poet and author Hans Christian Andersen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ugly_Duckling in which a bird grows up thinking it is an ugly duckling, only to later mature into a beautiful swan.

Comment: I wouldn't say "Cow" specifically means "fat", it is just an insult for an unpleasant woman.

Comment: Will update with more suggestions....

Comment: I think your meaning of unicorn is a derivative of the primary meaning as someone or something exceedingly rare and quite possibly mythical --"Oh man, you've done it!  You've found a unicorn!" It's not related to the sexual meaning of stallion.  Other than that, a very good and comprehensive rundown of animal based terms in common English usage.

Comment: Not "haws" - it's "hoss", as in "Hoss Cartwright" from the old TV series "Bonanza".

Comment: @ChrisSunami It may have started off that way, but it didn't stay that meaning. However, it is primarily used that way in the LGBT subculture, so I'll update it to as such.

Comment: "Chicken" is also slang for a woman, possibly derived from the earlier "chick" and/or "bird." And "bird" has a different meaning in the expression "weird bird."

Comment: "Batty" in the wrong context could end up incredibly offensive to Patois speakers :)

Comment: @rackandboneman That's news to me! Fill me in?

Comment: @liljoshu thought it could be mistaken for "battyman", which appears to be a very offensive term for gay men.

Answer (score 8):

We don't use an animal to describe something superior.

The use of "dog" in this slang sense is quite obscure. I'd probably understand the meaning in context, but it is rare enough that I can't recall ever hearing it used. The general sense of "inferior thing" is not found in other dictionaries

The slang meaning seems to be derived from the general idea of dogs, and animals in general being inferior.  There is no animal that commonly means "superior thing". But there is also no animal that commonly means "inferior thing".

That said, "[whale](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whale#Noun)" can be used figuratively for something that is large, and by extension important and excellent, in the idiom "a whale of a ...."

> My own father only wrote one poem in his life as far as I know, but it was a whale of a lyric, the kind you would give your whole life to write...

The expression "A whale of a time" common enough in casual speech (but it is a cliché) Other uses of "whale" to mean "excellent" are rare. I would not recommend using either "dog" or "whale" figuratively if you want to write clearly.

Comment: @ James, not sure if this is another example of Am E vs Br E but this expression is not uncommon in the area of the US where I live.

Comment: "The slang meaning seems to be derived from the general idea of dogs, and animals in general being inferior" - or a shortening of "dogshit", similar to "bull".

Comment: In my part of the US, it's not uncommon to hear something that's slow to be referred to as a "dog."  "Man, that car is a *dog* coming off of the starting line."  I do not know the etymology for why we use that word.

Comment: @CortAmmon-ReinstateMonica But then again to refer to a bad car in the US, you'd say "lemon". [E.g., the 24h of Lemons cup, riffing off the famous 24h of Lemans]. Above, "whale" is obviously big, so "whaling" on somebody is in a fight giving big powerful blows with little resistance.

Comment: I think the verb "whaling on someone" has a different etymology (with spelling influence by the name of the animal). It is, however, a different and non-cognate word.

Comment: @CortAmmon-ReinstateMonica I've heard of **dog-slow** but never **x is a dog**.  What part of the US says that?

Comment: @whn it's been common usage in the south for decades.

Comment: @whn Southwest US.

Comment: James - great point on "whale of a time".

Comment: It is fairly common in gambling and other high-margin businesses to refer to rich high-spending customers as "whales", but that is not necessarily meant as a compliment. They are customers you can reliably take advantage of.

Comment: 'We don't use an animal to describe something superior.' is true in the lion's share of cases, but not all

Comment: As a British English speaker, I'm not sure I would say "that film was a real dog", but I would certainly understand it.

Answer (score 3):

A Bear can be a very tough, difficult task.

In general, using negative analogies to dogs is falling out of fashion: Dogs are members of our families. They protect our children and love us unconditionally. Most English speakers treat dogs with the same care and courtesy that they treat other people.

For example, when a terrorist gets "shot like a dog", it is common for people to retort "Don't insult dogs like that".

Update: You can also be busy as a beaver and you can be an eager beaver.

People with beautiful eyes can be doe eyed (A doe is a female deer).

People with a busy social calendars are social butterflies.

Comment: "Sick as a dog" is still used now and again, as evidenced in Google Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sick+as+a+dog&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csick%20as%20a%20dog%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsick%20as%20a%20dog%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSick%20as%20a%20dog%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Csick%20as%20a%20dog%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsick%20as%20a%20dog%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSick%20as%20a%20dog%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "Most English speakers treat dogs with the same care and courtesy that they treat other people." _Some_ do, but I think _most_ is an exaggeration. Many (but still possibly not most) treat dogs with more respect than most other animals, but I think most people will still put people first. I've never heard anyone object to "shot like a dog in the street". Maybe you are describing a regional thing.

Answer (score 3):

"Stud!" "Stud-ly!" A stud being a male horse used for breading other horses. Indicating it has those desirable qualities worthy of surviving the gene pool. (Males typically view it a positive thing to be overused for ... reproduction ... not sure how a woman would feel about it, though.)

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat tenuous but you might also hear people mention a Golden Goose in reference to Aesop's fable of [the goose that laid the golden egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goose_That_Laid_the_Golden_Eggs), or a [cash cow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cash_cow) meaning a business venture that generates a steady return of profits.

Comment: Aesop never mentioned that the *goose* was golden - only the egg she laid. The *golden goose* was from Brothers Grimm.

Comment: @Tim True, but it has become fairly common parlance in English to shorten this to "golden goose" as per the following statement from the Wikipedia article referenced.

>The English idiom "Kill not the goose that lays the golden egg", sometimes shortened to "killing the **golden goose**", derives from this fable. (emphasis mine)

Comment: Possibly, but that doesn't make much sense, as the goose was in fact normally coloured! I like the 'cash cow', and with that, one can milk the profits...

Comment: Language is funny like that sometimes.

Comment: @Tim It makes about as much sense as "raining cats and dogs" or "bees' knees" but that's English for you!

Comment: Maybe one of the reasons English is so difficult to learn?!

Comment: "Cash Cow" has interpersonal meaning too.  The interpersonal meaning/connotation is decidedly "not positive", IMHO. But that kind of depends on where you personally land on the spectrum of answers to the question of how much one should accept "free" infusions of cash into one's personal economy.  For people with a certain sense of self-reliance, the term "cash cow" carries much more negative connotation than positive. For others, "self-reliance" can mean always taking the shortest route, so having and regularly milking a "cash cow" would be seen as positive from that perspective.

Comment: Can confirm, the goose that lays the golden egg is often shortened to "the golden goose".

Answer (score 1):

'***Mutt's nuts***' comes to mind - rather like earlier answers, but far more poetic! And agreeable in most class-related situations!

EDIT: on the other hand, someone who has a high opinion of themselves might feel that they are the ***cat's whiskers***. So, reference to an animal describing 'high quality' - if only in the eyes of the beholder!

Comment: this is equivalent to the dog's proverbial from Nikos' answer.  
Also : premium, cherry, choice, primo, ripper, bonzer, champion (and perversely: sick or filthy).

Comment: @mckenzm - understood, although there is a modicum of decorum in 'mutt's nuts'. And all the other  adjectives you offer are not animal related.

Answer (score 1):

Another slang term is "[cat's ass](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/cat's-ass)". Obviously you'd want to be careful where you use it.

> That party was the cat's ass.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cat%27s_pyjamas) also mentions a few others (in conjunction with "cat's pajamas"), **none** of which I am even vaguely familiar with as a native speaker (Canada):

> the snake's hips
>
> the spider's ankles (Ireland)
>
> the ant's pants (Australia)

---

We also have the much more mainstream [lionhearted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lionhearted), meaning brave.

> Traditionally young Masai men are consigned to a period of isolation in the bush in order to turn them into strong, lionhearted warriors

Comment: "cat's ass" is something i have only heard old people who smoke crack from Ontario say until now. Is this an east coast thing or a crack head thing

Comment: @DmitriDB Ontario is not on any coast, but it might be an Eastern Canada thing, like bagged milk. I have never had any contact with drug subculture elements, with the possible exception of a musician or two, and I doubt crack would be their drug of choice.

Answer (score 0):

James mentioned bears. In another context we also have bear markets, i.e. when stocks are performing badly - and bull markets for when they're performing well. From this we can get more generally that one is feeling bullish.

Answer (score 0):

Goat.
While not necessarily referring to the animal, the acronym G.O.A.T. (Greatest of All Time) is often used to describe exceptional things/people.